# Qt: Should accessing data structure in a list through deep copy be significantly slower than accessing it through a pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I hope my question was clear as I did not know how to phrase it. Here is the example code as it is quite short:

```
int N = 20;
unsigned int M = 100000000;
QList<Node> nodes;
QList<Node*> nodePointers;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    nodes << Node(i);
    nodePointers << new Node(i);
}

QElapsedTimer timer;

timer.start();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    int index = qrand() % N;
    if (nodes.at(index).getValue() == Node::V_0){
        nodes[index].setValue(Node::V_1);
    }
    else{
        nodes[index].setValue(Node::V_0);
    }
}

qWarning() << "Time for direct access test:" << timer.elapsed() << " ms";

timer.start();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    int index = qrand() % N;
    if (nodePointers.at(index)->getValue() == Node::V_0){
        nodePointers.at(index)->setValue(Node::V_1);
    }
    else{
        nodePointers.at(index)->setValue(Node::V_0);
    }
}

qWarning() << "Time for pointer access test:" << timer.elapsed() << " ms";
```

I need a list of data structures named nodes. I wanted to test the difference in reading and writing one of its values by using the [] operator (which, I understand does a deep copy) and accessing the data structure through a pointer. The code above does 100 Millions Reads and Writes to random nodes on two lists, one of the objects themselves and the other with pointers to the nodes themselves.

However running the code, resulted in only VERY mild differences. The values were around:

```
Time for direct access test: 2671  ms
Time for pointer access test: 2540  ms
```

Only 100 ms seemed too low of a difference. Am I thinking something wrong, here?

Comment: Why are you not using `at()` with both to make the comparison fair?

Comment: If I use at() the value in the data structrue cannot be mofied as at returns a const of the object. In the pointer case, it will simply return a const of the pointer.

Comment: @aarelovich - what is `Node` and most importantly, how big is a node?

Comment: I has a couple of properties and values. It is definitely not very big. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: i dont see the difference between the two verions. The big difference (in terms of copies) is when you fill the list, but you are not measuring that part, but in the part that you measure I dont see any deep copies of the nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the size of T is larger than the size of a pointer, `QList` will actually use pointers internally, and transparently to the user. Depending on the size of your node, both solutions might involve pointers.

There is no deep copying taking place in your code. Deep copying takes place when you pass the list as a value and that copy modifies the content of the list versus the original, at this point the internal data is deep-copied and the change is applied to it.

If anything, in case you really are storing those objects by value, access should be faster, because you will be avoiding an additional indirection. Each list index will give you the actual object, rather than a pointer to some other place in memory where the object is.

As of why it is slightly faster with pointers - the problem might be with your test. That random number doesn't give you the same sequence of indices in both test runs. You might want to seed with an identical value before each run to put the two runs on more equal ground. Also, at that difference, over that period of time, the result is subject to margin of error.

Answer (score 0):

While storing objects in containers like `QList`, they create a copy of the object and store it there. But with pointers, just the pointer to the original object is stored.

The deep copying may be expensive for objects that are large in size, but is a good thing to do as copies will be created if you're not sure about when the original object itself may go out of scope. However, of course, it may be slower.

The pointer way is good because it will of course perform faster. However, may lead to weird problems if the object being pointed to goes out of scope. You will have no way to detect something like that from within the list.

Comment: There is no deep copying taking place in that code.